# Running proxied repos in Gitlab?

Tags: maven, gitlab, nexus, artifact

I have a project that uses Nexus, and Nexus has a proxy / mirrored repo to Maven Central.

I need to transition to using Gitlab, but this is a corporate Gitlab with strict ways for me to enhance it. I saw that I could create a GitLab Maven proxy, but then GitLab has to be configured according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/dependency_proxy.html, which I'm not sure they will allow.

Are there other ways in which I can achieve a proxied repo with Gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to achieve that.

Currently (Gitlab version 13.9), dependency proxy is only possible for [Docker Images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/#use-the-dependency-proxy-for-docker-images).

Checking this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/9163#note_488942080), proxy for maven and npm seem to be planned in Gitlab 14 milestone

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#speed-up-your-builds-with-the-maven-dependency-proxy) (January 2024) starts to support that kind of feature (but only for Premium or Ultimate GitLab instances):

> ### Speed up your builds with the Maven dependency proxy
>
> A typical software project relies on a variety of dependencies, which we call packages. Packages can be internally built and maintained, or sourced from a public repository.
> Based on our user research, we’ve learned that most projects use a 50/50 mix of public and private packages. Package installation order is very important, as using an incorrect package version can introduce breaking changes and security vulnerabilities into your pipelines.
>
> Now you can add one external Java repository to your GitLab project. After adding it, when you install a package using the dependency proxy, GitLab first checks for the package in the project. If it’s not found, GitLab then attempts to pull the package from the external repository.
>
> When a package is pulled from the external repository, it’s imported into the GitLab project. The next time that particular package is pulled, it’s pulled from GitLab and not the external repository.
> Even if the external repository is having connectivity issues and the package is present in the dependency proxy, pulling the package still works, making your pipelines faster and more reliable.
>
> If the package changes in the external repository (for example, a user deletes a version and publishes a new one with different files) the dependency proxy detects it. It invalidates the package, so GitLab pulls the newer one. This ensures the correct packages are downloaded, and helps reduce security vulnerabilities.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/dependency_proxy/) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3610).